# What does a linear transformation of $\mathbf{C}^2$ look like?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, physics

This is a math question, but is based on a physics topic I'm trying to develop an intuition for. Let me know if this question would be better placed in physics.

**What I know:**
The "characteristic matrix" in thin film optics relates the E and H field amplitudes before and after passing through a thin film of material. For a single layer on a substrate, the equation is:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    E_b \\ H_b 
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\delta) & i(1/y_1)\sin(\delta) \\
    iy_1 \sin(\delta) &  \cos(\delta) \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     E_a \\ H_a 
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $E_a,H_a$ are the field amplitudes at the film/substrate interface, $E_b,H_b$ are the field amplitudes at the air/film interface, $\delta$ = the phase thickness of the material, $y_1$ = characteristic admittance of the thin film. It can also be written in terms of the substrate admittance by normalizing to $E_a$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    B \\ C 
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\delta) & i(1/y_1)\sin(\delta) \\
    iy_1 \sin(\delta) &  \cos(\delta) \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     1 \\ y_{sub} 
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

I was playing around with the matrix, when I realized: if you view $M$ as a linear transformation of $\mathbf{C}$, it corresponds to a pure rotation and scaling of the basis vectors (1,0) and (0,$ i$). In other words, for vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the complex plane, $M\mathbf{v}$ would rotate $\mathbf{v}$ by $\delta$ and then it's components would both be scaled by $y_1$ and $(1/y_1)$. See below for how the basis vectors rotate while staying normal to one another for $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    0 \\ iy_1 
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & i(1/y_1) \\
    iy_1 &  0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     1 \\ 0 
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    -(1/y_1) \\ 0
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & i(1/y_1) \\
    iy_1 &  0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     0 \\ i 
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

I thought this was a really interesting geometric interpretation of what this matrix was doing, until I realized that the vectors $(E_a, H_a)$ or $(1, Y_{sub})$ have complex components themselves and therefore don't exist in $\mathbf{C}$, but actually in $\mathbf{C}^2$ or $\mathbf{R}^4$.

**What I don't know:** So my questions now are, what does a linear transformation look like in $\mathbf{C}^2$? Does my pure rotation + scaling idea still make sense for this matrix? I'm not sure I even understand what $\mathbf{C}^2$ looks like much less how it would be transformed by a complex matrix...

Comment: No, in two dimensions (the fact that this is C rather than $R^2$ is irrelevant to this problem) a linear transformation may be interpreted as a rotation, a translation, **and** a "stretch" or "compression" in one or more directions.

Comment: Right, I think I understand how to visualize a linear transformation in $\mathbf{C}$ (rotation, translation, and stretches) but I'm not sure how that extends to $\mathbf{C}^2$? The input vector $(1,y_{sub})$ to this problem is in $\mathbf{C}^2$, but I'm not sure what $\mathbf{C}^2$ looks like and whether the characteristic matrix still rotates the bases of $\mathbf{C}^2$?

Comment: I suggest you read about the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{C}^2$ is a bit of a mirage.   You may change your basis to
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    E_b \\ H_b 
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\delta) & i(1/y_1)\sin(\delta) \\
    iy_1 \sin(\delta) &  \cos(\delta) \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     E_a \\ H_a 
     \end{pmatrix} \qquad \mapsto \qquad  \\  \begin{pmatrix} 
    E_b \\ iH_b 
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\delta) & (1/y_1)\sin(\delta) \\
    -y_1 \sin(\delta) &  \cos(\delta) \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     E_a \\ iH_a 
     \end{pmatrix},
$$
so the transition matrix is , in fact, a real rotation and scaling, unimodular,
 $$
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1/\sqrt{  y_1 } &  0 \\
     0 &  \sqrt{y_1}   \\
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\delta) &  \sin(\delta) \\
    -  \sin(\delta) &  \cos(\delta) \\
    \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
    \sqrt{y_1 } &  0 \\
     0 & 1/ \sqrt{y_1 }  \\
    \end{pmatrix} .
$$

Comment: Ah I was thinking change of basis would help. This makes sense if I know $E_a$ and $H_a$ are real. Then with the basis $(E_a , iH_a)$, I see how it corresponds to a real rotation/scaling like you said. However, $E_a$ and $H_a$ can be complex: 
$$  
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     E_a \\ H_a 
     \end{pmatrix} = 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     a+ib \\ c+id  
     \end{pmatrix} 
$$
The admittance also can be complex if the material is absorbing:  
$$  
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     1 \\ y_{sub} 
     \end{pmatrix} = 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     1 \\ n-ik  
     \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Sure, but the linear transformation itself *preserves the phase of the two-vectors* acted on, so it really is a real transformation.